# include and get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, include

What is the difference between a php include and the wordpress get_template_part other then you have a fallback option on the latter? Can I as well use a php include instead?

Answer (score 3):

I was also wondering about this recently and the article that I found very useful was this:

[How to Include and Require Files and Templates in WordPress](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/how-to-include-and-require-files-and-templates-in-wordpress/)

The author of the article follows these guidelines:

> - In theme development, I always use get_template_part().
> - In plugin development, I almost always use include_once() and I    generally use it once in a function. You can see this in my boilerplates.
> - If the plugin I’m writing is going to be used on a very large site,    then I use require_once().

**UPDATE**

According to [another article](http://voodoopress.com/get_template_part-in-my-wordpress-theme/), using get_template_part() is especially useful when trying to build a child theme, but I guess you already know that:).

Maybe the best way to know the difference is to check the source code of [get_template_part()](http://wpseek.com/get_template_part/)

Comment: Thanks... but I don't see why the author thinks that get_template_part('loop' 'standard'); is a better solution than include( 'loop-standard.php' );

Answer (score 2):

get_template_part also allows `child themes` to override that file and include additional more specific files.

For example, if you used `get_template_part( 'loop', 'single' )` and your theme only has a file named loop.php then a `child theme` could include a file named loop-single.php that would override your loop.php.